# In app web view not showing alerts that the web page shows

Tags: android, webview

I have a web view in my application. It show multiple web pages as per the code logic.

My issue is that many of my web pages have a **Cancel Button** on click this button, the webpage asks for a confirmation. **"Do you want to cancel this task"**, but the app never shows that dialog, and no action is done when the Cancel button is pressed.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Here's my web view code:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(activity, paymentDataModel),"android");
    webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            webView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {

        }
    };

    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try WebChromeClient instead of WebViewClient.

Comment: @ashiaka can i add both?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But I recommend to use WebChromeClient. If you have issues regarding the min SDK version of your app you can for example implement two methods, one using WebViewClient one using WebChromeClient. Then you can use annotations for these methods @TargetApi(int) so the compiler will still compile if WebChromeClient isn't available for the oldest SDK target version. Anyway you will have to check for the used SDK version programmatically und call the correct version of the method.

Comment: I'm afraid I misunderstood your question. Using both should be no problem :)